Google Sigin in Unity Profile Picture Greyed out
I'm using this code to get the profile picture and name from google, but the image becoming grey after signing in. Here's the code, i'm not a programmer but i do have basic code understanding. can you guys look at it
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using TMPro;
 
public class PlayGamesManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text DetailText;
    public Image img;
    public GameObject hidesign;
    void Start()
    {
        Signin();
        StartCoroutine(localImage());
    }
 
    public void Signin()
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate(ProcessAuthentication);
 
    }
    internal void ProcessAuthentication(SignInStatus status)
    {
        if (status == SignInStatus.Success)
        {
            // Continue with Play Games Services
            string name = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetUserDisplayName();
            string id = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetUserId();
            string ImgUrl = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetUserImageUrl();
 
            DetailText.text = "Welcome \n " + name;
            hidesign.SetActive(false);
 
        }
        else
        {
            DetailText.text = "Please Login";
            hidesign.SetActive(true);
            // Disable your integration with Play Games Services or show a login button
            // to ask users to sign-in. Clicking it should call
            // PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ManuallyAuthenticate(ProcessAuthentication).
        }
    }
 
    IEnumerator localImage()
    {
        Texture2D tex;
        while (Social.localUser.image == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Google image not found");
            yield return null;
        }
        Debug.Log("Google image found");
        tex = Social.localUser.image;
        img.sprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, tex.width, tex.height), new Vector2(0f,0f));
    }
}

Google Signin successfully worked and but profile pic is greyed out in the canvas. I must be doing something wrong with the sprite or i dunno.

Does the log "Google image found" appear? i think you need to call StartCoroutine(localImage()); after the sign in process successful.

Yes it appears in the Debug log, lemme check the StartCoroutine after the sigin in and get back to you. Thank you bro

still not showing the profile picture, same grey box image, checked in the playconsole internal testing. any idea whats going on ?

maybe these 2 links can solve the issue. check this and this . there is a bug. You must first call Social.localUser.userName (and - or - Social.localUser.id)

Nope its not working and giving me a big headache. I think i should open up a issue there.
